# How can I check the difference between sc_buffer and sc_signal?

Tags: c++, systemc, gtkwave

I would like to check the difference between using `sc_buffer` and `sc_signal`. I have coded a module which adds two random numbers and then I run two tests in parallel: one using `sc_buffer` and the other using `sc_signal`. Nevertheless, when I check with `gtkwave` I see the same traces for both examples, so I think for this case there should not be any difference. How can I check the difference? or is it that these two different types of channel are intended for different applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sc_buffer` is probably most useful when modeling at an abstract level.

For example, consider modeling a serial communication channel. The transmitter could send **the same character twice in a row**. If an `sc_signal` was used as the channel, the receiver wouldn't detect the second character, but with an `sc_buffer`, it would.

```cpp
#include <systemc>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sc_core;
using namespace std;

struct Transmitter : public sc_module {

    sc_out<char> out;

    Transmitter(sc_module_name name) : sc_module(name) {
        SC_THREAD(transmit);
    }

    void transmit() {
        wait(1, SC_NS);
        out.write('x');

        wait(1, SC_NS);
        out.write('x');

        wait(1, SC_NS);
        out.write('y');
    };

    SC_HAS_PROCESS(Transmitter);
};

struct Receiver : public sc_module {

    sc_in<char> in;

    Receiver(sc_module_name name) : sc_module(name) {
        SC_METHOD(receive);
        sensitive << in;
        dont_initialize();
    }

    void receive() {
        cout << sc_time_stamp() << ": " << name() << " received "
             << in.read() << endl;
    }

    SC_HAS_PROCESS(Receiver);
};

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sc_signal<char> signal;
    sc_buffer<char> buffer;

    Transmitter signal_transmitter("signal_transmitter");
    Receiver signal_receiver("signal_receiver");
    Transmitter buffer_transmitter("buffer_transmitter");
    Receiver buffer_receiver("buffer_receiver");

    signal_transmitter.out(signal);
    signal_receiver.in(signal);

    buffer_transmitter.out(buffer);
    buffer_receiver.in(buffer);

    sc_start();

    return 0;
}
```

The above example produces this output:

```
1 ns: signal_receiver received x
1 ns: buffer_receiver received x
2 ns: buffer_receiver received x
3 ns: signal_receiver received y
3 ns: buffer_receiver received y
```

Notice that `signal_receiver` didn't detect the character sent at 2 ns.

You won't see any difference in a VCD trace, because the values stored in the `sc_buffer` and `sc_signal` channels are identical. The difference is when the receiver is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the answer below for the differences between `sc_buffer` and `sc_signal`.

[In SystemC, can the sc_signal_in/out type port be bound to the primary channel sc_buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824286/in-systemc-can-the-sc-signal-in-out-type-port-be-bound-to-the-primary-channel-s)

`sc_buffer` is basically derived from `sc_signal` and it re-implements the `write` and `update` functions to generate notification for every change. 
So if your generate new numbers which are same as the previous number written into the channel and you are dumping some output at each event notification you should see some difference.

Comment: thanks, I have already read that post but it is still not clear to me under which situation would it be necessary to know if a channel has been written to. In the example I mentioned I have tried also by always adding the same two numbers, so everytime I get the same result. Nevertheless, when I check the traces in `gtkwave` I see the same results. I don't know if this is normal or if this is not the right place to check the value-change event when the buffer is written.

Comment: Possibly you may not see the difference in the waveform , because the buffer change trigger generates the same value  and your method will process and generate exactly the same output  . => The input and output will continue to remain the same even though a trigger was produced by the buffer and will appear to be the same output as the sc_signal which has not produced a change. If you do some kind of display ( cout) you should be able to see extra display in the terminal when the sc_buiffer can used .